# Can I check non-html responses in geb?

Tags: testing, groovy, webtest, geb

Geb is a nice framework for testing web applications, as there is very direct support for checking specific DOM elements as seen by the browsing client.  However, sometimes the expected result of a request is plain text (or csv, json, etc).

Is there any way to get the raw text of a result?  Can I also get the response code (e.g. 200) and the content-type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the page source can be retrieved with the getPageSource() method on the driver:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab("org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:latest.release"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:latest.release")
])
import geb.Browser
import geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory

Browser.drive("http://geb.codehaus.org/latest/")  {

    assert title == "Geb - Groovy Browser Automation"

    println driver.pageSource
}

CachingDriverFactory.clearCacheAndQuitDriver()
```

Comment: as for reading the http response take a look at this issue: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141